# pymongo insert new attribute using update_many() using current attribute values

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a document with the following attributes:

```
{'_id':1, 
  'longitude':1.1 //double, 
  'latitude':1.2 //double}
}
```

I would like to add `2D geo index` using `pymongo`.

I have the following code:

```
collection.create_index([('loc', pymongo.GEO2D)])
data = collection.update_many({},
                          {'$set':{'loc':['$latitude','$longitude']}})
```

But the result I get is an error
`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: location object expected, location array not in correct format`

It's because I am inserting 2 strings and '$latitude','$longitude'. How do I insert the actual values of latitude and longitude instead?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Update: I know I can do it with a for loop. But I want to avoid doing that because it will be extremely slow.

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ? You code of using existing fields `'$latitude','$longitude'` doesn't work for any version below `4.2`, if your version is <`4.2` better upgrade to latest if you can , else you need to read manipulate data & write it back to doc..

Comment: MongoDB shell version v4.2.3

Comment: Try this :: `collection.update_many({},
    [{ '$set': { 'loc': ['$latitude', '$longitude'] } }])`

Answer (score 0):

`$set` operation seems not to support [2D indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2d/) on `Collection.update`.

2D indexes are legacy and support for `$set` may likely not be added.

Use an aggregation to fix your current issue as follow:

```
field = {'loc': ['$longitude', '$latitude']}
# write documents with added field as a workaround to $set not supporting
# legacy 2D indexes
collection.aggregate([{'$addFields': field}, {'$out': 'collection-name'}])
```

I strongly recommend to consider using [2Dsphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/) indexes.
`2Dsphere` supports all geospatial queries and could be beneficial for your usecase in the long run.